# How to make images zoom when clicked on tumblr?

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming, tumblr

I use the publishers theme for tumblr, and my content is in the pages of my blog rather than as traditional tumblr posts, as it's a portfolio. The images can be quite small and I'd love for viewers to be able to click on an image to make it larger.

I've searched and searched and found no way of doing this that I could understand, so I need your help! 
My tumblr is http://www.alliedaviesportfolio.tumblr.com.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sadly this question lacks minimal understanding and effort, which is required by the site to post questions. If you can show what you have tried, I am sure someone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no built in functionality to do that. There are many JS/jQuery-based libraries that will do that for you, such as Magnific, HighSlide, and TopUp. There are also tutorials [like this one](http://webdesignandsuch.com/how-to-create-a-popup-with-css-and-javascript/) on how to create your own from scratch. Since the solution is nontrivial, I suggest you take a look at those resources and come back if you have any questions relevant to your specific implementation.